# Maximum density created on Earth artificially?

Tags: pressure, density

One reads that a single tea spoon or cubic centimeter of a neutron star would weigh as much as a mountain. My question is, in attempts to compress matter either for practical reasons (like the "Fat Man" type a-bomb) or maybe just for the sake of experimentally compressing matter, what sort of densities have been achieved for a significant quantity of matter, like a CC? How long would it last?

In the Fat Man, the compression was achieved using conventional explosives and only lasted for micro seconds.

But there are also diamond presses which they have tried to make solid hydrogen with. If metal like iron was compressed in such a device, would one be able to achieve, with pressure applied, a much more dense version of iron? If so, would such material be very unstable, decompressing perhaps explosively as soon as pressure was released?

Comment: "*If so, would such material be very unstable, decompressing perhaps explosively as soon as pressure was released?*" Yes

Comment: This is the record Pressure in 2015. Unfortunately it relates to your question just marginally, as for apparently Os keeps about its density nevertheless. I think this latter behavior is anyway surprising and interesting. https://tinyurl.com/yf9row7q It seems the answer depends on what is compressed.

Comment: @Alchimista: my reading is that a piece of really dense stuff was not created despite the huge pressure used but that it began to affect the electrons of the material -- that is kind of amazing, isn't it? Could greater pressures even affect the nucleus, fusion from just mechanical forces? In the hydrogen experiments, afaik hydrogen remained hydrogen but who knows? Would it make sense to both pressurize H and then bombard it with neutrons?

Comment: @releseabe that is the point I didn't get. Density not affected but inner electrons yes. It should be that a little change in density triggered inner interactions. I stop here because all this maked me think even at degeneracy P and stuff like that but I have no the tools to do that. For your final question, well if one read mechanical as P that's what happens in bombs and stars, though T is involved too. It is where I don't have the tools, as written just above.